# Find and replace regex in Intellij, but keep some of the matched regex?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, replace

I changed an array to a list, so I want to change all instances of `myObject[index]` to `myObject.get(index)` where index is different integers. I can find these instances by doing

```
`myObject\[.*\]`
```

However, I am not sure what I should put in the replace line - I don't know how to make it keep the `index` values.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the following regex replacement:

*Find*: `myObject\[(.*?)\]`
*Replace*: `myObject.get($1)`

If the `index` is an integer, you may replace `(.*?)` with `(\d+)`.

The pair of unescaped parentheses creates a capturing group that we may reference from the replacement pattern using `$` + Group ID. `$1` will insert the index into the replacement result.

Comment: Is there a terminology for this kind of search and replace?

Comment: @BenjaminZach This is a basic regex replacement, this is why regex replacement was invented: replacing text in-context (replacing a part of a match only) when a capturing group is used in the regex and the corresponding placeholder is used in the replacement pattern.